# Why am I getting "Cannot find module" error on "tsc" command, only on GitHub Actions?

Tags: typescript, github, github-actions, tsc

[This build](https://github.com/aabuhijleh/tpot/actions/runs/5395955837/jobs/9799071493) keeps failing on this type check step `tsc --noEmit`

```bash
> tpot@0.1.0 typecheck /home/runner/work/tpot/tpot
> tsc --noEmit

Error: src/components/Navbar.tsx(21,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module '~public/tpot.png' or its corresponding type declarations.
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 2.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

[tsconfig.json is configured correctly.](https://github.com/aabuhijleh/tpot/blob/main/tsconfig.json)

**This failure is only happening on Github Actions.** The command is working well locally and the vercel build is succeeding. I've tried a lot of things like changing the file name,  changing the imports to relative instead of absolute but nothing worked.

I need a hint on why this might be happening.

Comment: Unsure what would be the cause of the difference between your local and the runner, but you could try adding the type declaration; make a `./public/index.d.ts` with `declare module '*.png' {
  const value: any;
  export = value;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boilerplate code [create-t3-app](https://create.t3.gg) I used, ignored `next-env.d.ts` type declaration file from git which included a lot of types including image types.

This is why `tsc --noEmit` is working locally but not on GitHub CLI.

I just added this file to the repo and the build is succeeding ✅